# problem with Installing gfpgan for stable diffusion error code 1

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, stable-diffusion

I decided to install Diffusion Stable today. But unfortunately, I have been seeing various errors since morning. The first case was related to Torch. I took a 2.4 GB file and forcibly installed Stable Diffusion on Python(in script folder) itself. The error was fixed, but now I get a new error when installing gfpgan. Even by downloading the file that gives the error and installing it on Python in the script folder, the error is not fixed. My Python version was 11 at first, but I completely deleted it and restarted the system several times and installed exactly the version it wanted. I get this error when I get to install backend dependencies during gfpgan installation. It pauses for a few seconds and crashes. **I did everything like purge but it didn't work**.

**here is complete text :**

```
venv "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version: v1.4.1
Commit hash: f865d3e11647dfd6c7b2cdf90dde24680e58acd8
Installing gfpgan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 29, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 274, in prepare_environment
    run_pip(f"install {gfpgan_package}", "gfpgan")
  File "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 130, in run_pip
    return run(f'"{python}" -m pip {command} --prefer-binary{index_url_line}', desc=f"Installing {desc}", errdesc=f"Couldn't install {desc}", live=live)
  File "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 107, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install gfpgan.
Command: "F:\d\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/archive/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379.zip --prefer-binary
Error code: 1
stdout: Collecting https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/archive/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/archive/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379.zip (6.0 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 6.0/6.0 MB 245.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'

stderr:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [15 lines of output]
  Collecting numpy
    Obtaining dependency information for numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/07/cab4129005dba3f170dd1a2cfa312fc71100f0e26b91f7fc659b6b5abbdc/numpy-1.25.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata
    Using cached numpy-1.25.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
  Collecting cython
    Obtaining dependency information for cython from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/0b/889b9b839ea7237eb6048191fe653c17ce93e298495eaf8f893cff748951/Cython-3.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata
    Using cached Cython-3.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
  Downloading numpy-1.25.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (15.0 MB)
     --------------------------               10.0/15.0 MB 290.1 kB/s eta 0:00:18
  Downloading Cython-3.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.8/2.8 MB 208.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
      unknown package:
          Expected sha256 c1516db588987450b85595586605742879e50dcce923e8973f79529651545b57
               Got        8cd0ee00a1e026d5d0731510951ca5648e1ab268339f05c3e531bd44f8f655cc

  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

my system :
core i3 6100
gtx 1060 6gb
ram 16gb ddr4

installing gfpgan for stable diffusion